# Linux ColdFusion cannot find uninstall instructions that work

Tags: ubuntu, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have ColdFusion 8 and am using Ubuntu.  It will no longer start, and I am no longer using it.  But it seems to be set up to start automatically on boot, and then to be throwing an error.

I would like to uninstall it, or at least stop it from running at boot.  I have searched the internet for uninstall instructions and found several which send me to folders or files that do not exist on my machine.  I do not know enough about Linux to be able to get ColdFusion out of the boot up.

Can someone give me usable instructions for uninstalling this, or at least getting it out of the boot up process?

Comment: The error message doesn't give any info as to what caused the error?

Comment: Can you tell us what steps you've made already to figure out where CF is being booted from? Have you looked at `/etc/init.d/` to see if there are any scripts being ran?

Comment: @fyroc I did look at /etc/init.d/ and found a link labelled 'coldfusion'.  However, I don't know whether deleting that will stop CF from trying to start up at boot.  Can you advise me?

Comment: @James A Mohler I didn't actually try to do anything, so I have no error messages.

Comment: I don't really know Linux, but isn't the purpose of init.d to start up services? Shouldn't you just be able to comment it out and confirm that it doesn't try to do anything?

Comment: @BettyMock that's the link you need to remove. Removing it should fix it from booting on start. Make a backup of it and store it somewhere other than the current directory though.

Answer (score 3):

The process to uninstall CF 8 should be the same as with CF 9. The docs aren't online, but I have a local copy. Depending on which version of Java you have installed, the script may or may not run correctly.

---

1. Log in as root.
2. Go to the `cf_root/uninstall` directory:

`cd /opt/jrun4/bin/uninstall`

3. Enter the following command:

`./uninstall.sh`

When the program completes, remove any remaining files and directories in the `cf_root` directory.

---

You can simply remove the entry from `init.d` as mentioned in the comments, but this should completely remove the application server files from your server.

Comment: I'd love to do this, but I do not have a jrun4 in opt

Comment: I have an uninstall directory in opt/coldfusion8, but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Does that folder contain a file named `uninstall.sh`? If so, that's most likely the script you need to run. The folder `/opt/jrun4/...` is just the default folder name for installation. Someone must have chosen to use `/opt/colfusion8`/ on your server. Read the contents of the uninstall file before you run it to make sure it looks like the right file.

Comment: No, the folder contains uninstall, uninstall.lax and uninstaller.jar along with some install files.